# Why Relu layer is not counted in memory requirements

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, caffe

I read this [lecture note](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#layerpat) and `Relu layer` is not counted for memory requirements.
Here is the sample calculation for memory requirements. But they don't consider Relu in both memory and parameter calculations.

```
INPUT: [224x224x3]        memory:  224*224*3=150K   weights: 0
CONV3-64: [224x224x64]  memory:  224*224*64=3.2M   weights: (3*3*3)*64 = 1,728
CONV3-64: [224x224x64]  memory:  224*224*64=3.2M   weights: (3*3*64)*64 = 36,864
POOL2: [112x112x64]  memory:  112*112*64=800K   weights: 0
CONV3-128: [112x112x128]  memory:  112*112*128=1.6M   weights: (3*3*64)*128 = 73,728
CONV3-128: [112x112x128]  memory:  112*112*128=1.6M   weights: (3*3*128)*128 = 147,456
POOL2: [56x56x128]  memory:  56*56*128=400K   weights: 0
CONV3-256: [56x56x256]  memory:  56*56*256=800K   weights: (3*3*128)*256 = 294,912
CONV3-256: [56x56x256]  memory:  56*56*256=800K   weights: (3*3*256)*256 = 589,824
CONV3-256: [56x56x256]  memory:  56*56*256=800K   weights: (3*3*256)*256 = 589,824
POOL2: [28x28x256]  memory:  28*28*256=200K   weights: 0
CONV3-512: [28x28x512]  memory:  28*28*512=400K   weights: (3*3*256)*512 = 1,179,648
CONV3-512: [28x28x512]  memory:  28*28*512=400K   weights: (3*3*512)*512 = 2,359,296
CONV3-512: [28x28x512]  memory:  28*28*512=400K   weights: (3*3*512)*512 = 2,359,296
POOL2: [14x14x512]  memory:  14*14*512=100K   weights: 0
CONV3-512: [14x14x512]  memory:  14*14*512=100K   weights: (3*3*512)*512 = 2,359,296
CONV3-512: [14x14x512]  memory:  14*14*512=100K   weights: (3*3*512)*512 = 2,359,296
CONV3-512: [14x14x512]  memory:  14*14*512=100K   weights: (3*3*512)*512 = 2,359,296
POOL2: [7x7x512]  memory:  7*7*512=25K  weights: 0
FC: [1x1x4096]  memory:  4096  weights: 7*7*512*4096 = 102,760,448
FC: [1x1x4096]  memory:  4096  weights: 4096*4096 = 16,777,216
FC: [1x1x1000]  memory:  1000 weights: 4096*1000 = 4,096,000

TOTAL memory: 24M * 4 bytes ~= 93MB / image (only forward! ~*2 for bwd)
TOTAL params: 138M parameters
```

Could somebody explain why?

Comment: Please edit the question to give us more details, so people do not have to read the whole article to understand the question (links die). What memory requirements? In what context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relu layer simply applies a fixed function that does not need to remeber any state. Thus there are no weights associated with a relu, it is the same function every time.